# Show that if $0\lt L\lt R\lt+\infty$, then $\int_L^R\frac{\sin x}x dx\lt \frac2L$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, inequality

Show that if $0\lt L\lt R\lt+\infty$, then $\int_L^R\frac{\sin x}x dx\lt \frac2L$

My Work:

a) Integration by parts: $$\int_L^R\frac{\sin x}x dx$$ using the formula $\int a'b=ab-\int ab'$, there is no viable selection for a or b because no amount of integration or derivation will make one of the two functions cancel out

b) Substitution: $u(x)=\frac1x$ $$\int_{u(L)}^{u(R)}u \sin{\frac1u} dx$$ From here we can try IBP again, but I believe that this will also prove to be fruitless because of the term $\sin{\frac1u}$

I don't know of any other method I could use to integrate this function and I'm rather puzzled on what to do next. Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: I wouldn't try to do this by integrating the function, but rather by some form of squeezing. The most obvious relevant point is that $-1\le\sin x\le 1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The biggest the integral from $L$ to $L+\pi$ could possibly be its value if $L$ happened to be an even multiple of $\pi$ (since then the sine function would be positive on that interval), and then we would have
$$
0 < \int_L^{L+\pi} \frac{\sin x} x\,dx \le \frac 1 L \int_L^{L+\pi} \sin x\,dx = \frac 2 L.
$$
But in that case, where $L$ happened to be an even multiple of $\pi$, we would also have
$$
0 > \int_{L+\pi}^{L+2\pi} \frac{\sin x} x \,dx \ge \frac 1 {L+\pi} \int_{L+\pi}^{L+2\pi} \sin x \, dx = \frac{-2}{L+\pi}.
$$
I wouldn't be surprised if that can be used. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$along with something about the alternating series $$
\frac 2 L - \frac 2 {L+\pi} + \frac 2 {L+2\pi} - \frac 2 {L+3\pi} + \cdots
$$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: My professor said that if the problem proved to be too difficult, we could use $\frac 4L$ in place of $\frac 2L$ for partial credit, if that facilitates your thought process...I think the squeeze theorem is probably the route to the solution, but I cannot figure it out

Comment: Now we have three answers here and I'm still the only one who's up-voted the question. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that
$$ \left|\int_L^R\frac{\cos x}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x  \right| \le \int_L^R\left|\frac{\cos x}{x^2} \right| \mathrm{d}x \le \int_L^R\frac{1}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{L} - \frac{1}{R}$$

Now,

\begin{align}\int_L^R \frac{\sin x}{x} \mathrm{d}x &= \left. \frac{-\cos x}{x}\right|_L^R - \int_L^R\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\mathrm{d}x \\ 
\overset{(a)}\implies \int_L^R \frac{\sin x}{x} \mathrm{d}x &\le \frac{\cos L}{L} - \frac{\cos R}{R} + \frac{1}{L} - \frac{1}{R} \\
&= \frac{1+\cos L}{L} - \underbrace{\frac{1+\cos R}{R}}_{\ge 0} \\
&\le \frac{1+\cos L}{L} \le \frac{2}{L}
\end{align}

where $(a)$ comes from $ x < y-z \implies x < y +|z|$

Comment: Intuitively, the new integral that you get after integrating by parts gives you an extra factor of $x$ in the denominator, which is helpful since $1/x^2$ is integrable at infinity whereas $1/x$ is not. It then basically remains to estimate with the boundary term from the integration by parts; conveniently, the upper bound on the new integral gives you an additional negative term (the $-1/R$) to play with.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_L^R = \int_L^{n\pi} + \overbrace{\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} + \int_{(n+1)\pi}^{(n+2)\pi} + \cdots + \int_{(m-1)\pi}^{m\pi}} + \int_{m\pi}^R
$$
where $n\pi$ is the smallest integer multiple of $\pi$ that is $\ge L$ and $m\pi$ is the largest integer multiple of $\pi$ that is $\le R$. If $n$ is even then we have
$$
0 < \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \frac{\sin x} x\,dx < \frac 1 {n\pi} \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \sin x \, dx \le \frac 2 {n\pi} \tag 1
$$
and
$$
0 > \int_{(n+1)\pi}^{(n+2)\pi} \frac{\sin x} x \,dx \ge \frac 1 {(n+1)\pi} \int_{(n+1)\pi}^{(n+2)\pi} \sin x \, dx = \frac{-2}{(n+1)\pi}. \tag 2
$$
Thus the sum under the $\overbrace{\text{overbrace}}$ is less than $2/(n\pi)$ when we've added the first term, then decreases to something $>0$ when we add the second, then increases to something less than first term when we add the third, then decreases to something bigger than the sum of the first two terms when we add the fourth, and so on.  When we add the term after the overbrace, we don't go all the way to the next integer multiple of $\pi$, so we still get something between the last two terms that came before it.  (Still assuming $n$ is even), the integral before the overbrace is negative but somewhere between $0$ and $-2/L$.  Hence the integral from $L$ to $R$ must be between $\pm2/L$.

If $n$ is odd we just reverse some plus and minus signs.